# IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (10 … 10) ends beyond length 3

Tags: java, android, xml

Some times this error "IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (10 … 10) ends beyond length 3"
occurs in editText.setSelection() i.e when i want to focus back on that editText previous value from editText.getText.toString().length().

For Example:
editText.setSelection(editText.getText.toString().length());

Any ideas why it happen? And how to fix this??

Comment: a longer snippet of your code would probably be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ClearSpans() on edit text
Example :
      editText.getText.clearSpans();

You can Handle this using Xml by puting 
          '<'requestFocus/ >